# Can anybody say which plugins make this pic vim?

Tags: vim, php, code

[image]

With descriptions and arguments for functions and variables.
I need list of plugins which i need to isntall and my language is PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thats the builtin 'omnicomplete' feature of vim. you activate it with `ctrl-x ctrl-o`. additionally you will need to

```
:set wildmenu
:set completeopt += longest
```

very helpfull is the use of `ctags`, it creates kind of a database of available functions across your project. vim then uses that database to give you the list of available matches.
php is supported by ctags so you want to use ctags as well.

combine this with the help of `phpcomplete`( http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3171 ) and you should get very close to what you see on that picture.

also check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224838/vim-php-omni-completion.